# hook that when page is starting to load

Tags: php, hooks

I want to create a page loading message based on php when the wp page is starting to load.
is there a hook about it? simply like opposite of `wp_loaded`?

`wp_loaded` is after the page is fully loaded, I wan't the opposite of it..

Answer (score 1):

Well, when exactly do you consider the page to be "starting to load"?

[`get_header()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) is typically the first function to fire as the html of a theme is starting to generated. [It fires the `get_header` action](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L35). [Numerous hooks fire prior to that](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request), at different points, the very earliest being `muplugins_loaded` I believe.

`wp_loaded`, by the way, is not when the page has fully loaded but only after WordPress has loaded. There is a difference. A number of things happen before the page is created and sent to the browser.